# Медиазапрос не срабатывает с первой загрузки

Tags: css, html5

Здравствуйте! Один медиазапрос не срабатывает при загрузке страницы. Причем в отладочной панели в chrome он отображается (т.е его не перебивают другие стили и медиазапросы), но его изменения не отображаются, а отображаются от предыдущего медиазапроса. Но при перезагрузке странице он полностью срабатывает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может `ctrl + f5` поможет?

Comment: и код в студию.

Comment: ctrl+f5 как раз и помогает. Но первая загрузка страницы на новом устройстве всегда кривая. И в новой вкладке если заново открыть медиазапрос не срабатывает

Comment: //Первый медиазапрос (работает)
@media only screen and (max-width : 700px){
    
    .about_list{
         .about__item{
            
            &:nth-child(1) .about_item__title::before{
                top:80px;
                left: 50px;
            }

      
        }
    }

Comment: //Второй медиазапрос (срабатывает только после перезагрузки)
@media  (max-width : 380px){ .about_list{
         .about__item{

            &:nth-child(1) .about_item__title::before{
                top:140px;
                left: 100px;
                
                width: 201px;
            }
    }
    }

Comment: Точнее даже - ширина срабатывает, а позиционирование - нет

Comment: Код покажите...